# When selecting a item in a WPF listview update other controls to see detail

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a window that uses a viewmodel. This screen contains 2 listviews on a screen. The first listview binds to a propery on my viewmodel called projects. This property returns a model as follows

```
class ProjectsModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ProjectModel> ProjectDetails { get; set; }
}
```

In this class the ProjectModel looks like the following

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectFileId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectSource { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public string JobNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The first listview shows projectname as i expect but I would like it so that when I click on any of the items, the second listview should display its details of the projectdetails property. It almost appears to work has it shows the first items childrean but I beleive that its not being informed that the selected item of the first listview has changed. Ho can I do this? Any ideas would be appreciated becuase Ive been pulling my hair out for hours now!

This is the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TranslationProjectBrowser.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TranslationProjectBrowser.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TranslationProjectBrowser.Models"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="373" Width="452" Background="LightGray">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ProjectBrowserViewModel></vm:ProjectBrowserViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="projectList" ObjectType="{x:Type vm:ProjectBrowserViewModel}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource projectList}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="176*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="176*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="254*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Projects" Margin="5,2"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Name="ProjectName" Width="140" Margin="5,2" Height="18" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="10"></TextBox>
        <Button Height="18" Width="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2" FontSize="10" Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=AddProject}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ProjectName, Path=Text}"></Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ErrorText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,2" Foreground="DarkRed"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="project" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectName}" Header="Name" Width="200" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="1" >
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Project Files" Margin="5,2"></TextBlock>
        <ListView  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects/ProjectDetails}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectName}"  Width="200" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Job Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=JobNumber}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view models should (at least) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  This is how WPF will know when your selction (or other properties) change and the binding needs to be updated.

So you should have something like this:

```
class ProjectsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    public string ProjectName 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _projectName;
        }
        set
        {
            _projectName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProjectName");
        }       
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ProjectModel> ProjectDetails 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _projectDetails;
        }
        set
        {
            _projectDetails = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProjectDetails");
        }
    }
}
```

In future versions of the .NET framework this gets a lot easier with the "caller info" attributes (http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2012/06/13/using-c-5-caller-info-attributes-when-targeting-earlier-versions-of-the-net-framework/).  But as of today this is usually how it's done.

**UPDATE**

Ok, so based on your comment you need to bind your ListView's `SelectedItem` property to a property on your view model.  You can then Bind your second ListView to that property as well.  Something like this:

```
<ListView ... SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FirstListViewSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" .. >
```

And then your second list view would be sometihng like this:

```
<ListView ... ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FirstListViewSelectedItem.ProjectDetails, Mode=OneWay" .. />
```

Comment: It does implement INotifyPropertyChanged. In the case of properties changing I call OnPropertyChanged supplying the name of the proeprty that has changes. This scenario is differant as i would like the 2nd listview to update when the user clicks an item in the first listview

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any current management in your code. If you use a CollectionView you will get that for free, see below sample:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectsView}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectsView/ProjectDetails}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new VM();
        }
    }

    public class VM
    {
        public VM()
        {
            List<Project> projectsModel = new List<Project>();
            projectsModel.Add(new Project("AAA"));
            projectsModel.Add(new Project("BBB"));
            projectsModel.Add(new Project("CCC"));

            ProjectsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(projectsModel);
        }

        public ICollectionView ProjectsView { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public Project(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> ProjectDetails
        {
            get
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    yield return string.Format("{0}{1}", Name, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```